# Can move semantics help for a user-defined container built over an std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following code when a new container is defined over a `std::array`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

// My container
template<typename Type, unsigned int Size>
class MyContainer
{
    // Lifecycle
    public:
        MyContainer() : _data() {}
        MyContainer(const MyContainer<Type, Size>& rhs) : _data(rhs.data()) {}
        MyContainer(const std::array<Type, Size>& rhs) : _data(rhs) {}
        template<typename... Types> MyContainer(const Types&... numbers) : _data({{numbers...}}) {}
        ~MyContainer() {}

    // Assignment
    public:
        MyContainer<Type, Size>& operator=(const MyContainer<Type, Size>& rhs) {_data = rhs.data(); return *this}

    // Accessors
    public:
        Type& operator[](const unsigned int i) {return _data[i];}
        const Type& operator[](const unsigned int i) const {return _data[i];}
        std::array<Type, Size>& data() {return _data;}
        const std::array<Type, Size>& data() const {return _data;}

    // Operators
    public:
        MyContainer<Type, Size> operator+(const MyContainer<Type, Size>& rhs)
        {
            MyContainer<Type, Size> result;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
                result[i] = _data[i] + rhs[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

    // Data members
    protected:
        std::array<Type, Size> _data;
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialization
    MyContainer<double, 4> x = {0., 1., 2., 3.};
    MyContainer<double, 4> y = {4., 5., 6., 7.};
    MyContainer<double, 4> z;

    // Operation
    z = x+y; // Can move semantics help here ?

    // Result
    std::cout<<z[0]<<" "<<z[1]<<" "<<z[2]<<" "<<z[3]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can move semantics speed up the operation in the main() by avoiding some copies ?

If the answer is yes, how to implement it in the current design ?

Comment: In general, rvalues make things with pointers faster.  If you have no pointers, don't bother with rvalues.

Comment: you shouldn't defined constructors/operators that already do what you're implementing. Then the question becomes much simpler wr.t. the Rule of Five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  All of the data of a `std::array<double, N>` is contained within the object itself.  Move semantics only help when the object owns external referenced resources (usually via a pointer), and that reference can be copied and nullified.

Comment: And do you think that it would be preferable that MyContainer contains a pointer to a std::array and not an std::array ?

Comment: More generally: if the class owns any resources or has members that have move-constructors, then a move constructor is helpful. But in the former case the Rule of Five dictates such a thing anyway, and in the former the implicitly generated move constructor Does The Right Thing.

Comment: @Vincent: a pointer to a `std::array` seems silly to me, why not a `std::vector`?

Comment: @Vincent: I don't know.  What are your concerns?  Performance?  Then measure it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Because in the original code (not this one which is just an example), I compared the speed of two designs (one with std::array and one with std::vector, and the containers defined over std::array are faster (due to the memory allocation I suppose))

Comment: @Vincent: But I bet that a pointer to an `array` would make them almost if not exactly the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

For `MyContainer<double>` there's no advantage, when you "move" a `double` it actually does a copy, because a `double` has no resources to move, it only has a value to copy.

But your type is a template, so presumably you're going to use it for types other than `double`. For `MyContainer<std::string>` or `MyContainer<HeavyweightType>` it would be worth defining move operations.  That would be simple:

```
    MyContainer(MyContainer&&) = default;
    MyContainer& operator=(MyContainer&&) = default;
```

Note that you can just say `MyContainer` instead of `MyContainer<Type, Size>`, in a class template's definition the name of a class template without a template argument list refers to the current instantiation, i.e. `MyContainer` is the same type as `MyContainer<Type, Size>`.

You can simplify some of your other special member functions too:

```
    MyContainer(const MyContainer&) = default;
    ~MyContainer() = default;

    MyContainer& operator=(const MyContainer>&) = default;
```

Now your type is movable and copyable, with the right semantics, and the code is even simpler than your original version!

You could also add move support to these functions:

```
    MyContainer(const std::array<Type, Size>& rhs) : _data(rhs) {}
    template<typename... Types> MyContainer(const Types&... numbers) : _data({{numbers...}}) {}
```

by adding a constructor taking an rvalue `array`, and making the constructor template use universal references and perfect forwarding:

```
    MyContainer(const std::array<Type, Size>& rhs) : _data(rhs) {}
    MyContainer(std::array<Type, Size>&& rhs) : _data(std::move(rhs)) {}
    template<typename... Types> MyContainer(Types&&... numbers)
      : _data{{ std::forward<Types>(numbers)...}} {}
```

Now your type can be initialized with rvalues.